# Can't create an app engine module in Android studio 3.0

Tags: google-app-engine, module, android-studio-3.0

I'm working on an Android app with a Google app engine backend, but i can't find how to create the *app engine* module. In Android studio 3.0 there is no *app engine* module under:

*File->NewModule*.

How can I make the relation between the app in android studio and the backend in app engine?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding using the App Engine's backend with Android studio 3.0 [the documentation says](https://cloud.google.com/tools/android-studio/docs/):

> Creating **App Engine-based cloud backends is not supported in Android
>   Studio 3.0**; however, your existing projects with cloud backends will
>   continue to work in Android Studio.

There is more information about this in the provided link but also this ["Build an Android App Using Firebase and the App Engine Flexible Environment"](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-app-engine-flexible) could be interesting for your purposes.